# Need to read this array in php

Tags: php, arrays, soap

I am receiving a stdClass array from a soap server. But I don't understand how to read it.

I try it like a simple array but got this error

```
Cannot use object of type stdClass as array
```

This is the array:

```
object(stdClass)#2 (1) {
  ["RegistrarResult"]=>
  object(stdClass)#3 (23) {`enter code here`
    ["Anio"]=>
    NULL
    ["BancaId"]=>
    string(3) "WWW"
    ["Cedula"]=>
    string(11) "SSSS"
    ["CodigoConsorcio"]=>
    string(5) "EEEE"
    ["Color"]=>
    NULL
    ["Error"]=>
    NULL
    }
}
```

Comment: This is _not_ an array, it actually is an object. All you need to do is access the object's properties. You want to read about classes and objects in php...

Answer (score 0):

That is because it is an object, not an array. Use `->` to access the data.

Like this

```
$nameOfStdClassVariable->RegistrarResult->BancaId
```

Should return "WWW"